# How can i automate a spring boot batch process?

Tags: java, selenium, automation, cucumber, spring-batch

I am trying to see if i can automate a spring boot batch processing built with JDBC template and i have never worked on it. i automate web based projects using cucumber and selenium web driver. Is it even possible? help please.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, it is possible to write automated tests for spring boot batch application using cucumber.

This is how I have it implemented -

- Dependencies - cucumber-java, cucumber-junit, cucumber-spring
- gherkin features like usual
- cucumber test cases - use SpringApplication.run(YourApplication.class) to run the Spring Boot application, an use SpringApplication.exit() - to verify exit status codes for Batch as needed.

Here is an article which I found helpful for integrating cucumber with Spring Boot - http://www.baeldung.com/cucumber-spring-integration